# Is this the correct way of translating an algebraic equation to logical gates?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$x+(y\cdot z)+(x+y)\cdot(x+z)=f$

[Here is the image to my answer, Sorry if it is poorly drawn. I just did it in paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnxmO.jpg)

Comment: In your image, there are $2$ summands, in the equation there are $3$. This can't be right.

Comment: You could use some program for doing the image, this is what google gave me: https://academo.org/demos/logic-gate-simulator/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is [this](http://imgur.com/a/TZ8Fx) correct now?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't use that program, I tried but I don't know how to. Sorry. Please bare with my poorly drawn logic gate.

Comment: Your second drawing looks correct.

Comment: After trying it a little, the program I suggested was crap, I agree.

Comment: You might want to try [Logic Friday 1](http://sontrak.com/). It is capable of translating equations as well as truth-tables to circuits composed of logic gates.